# What causes the laser printer to print all pages with a washed out background?

Tags: laser-printer, toner

My HP LaserJet 1200 series laser printer is now printing all pages with a grey background from the toner covering the whole print area.  I can still see the printed letters as much darker, but this gray wash across the whole background looks bad.

I can think of two possible causes.

First, my replacement toner cartridge for the c7115a Toner Cartridge was a compatible one sold by Imagestore US Inc.  Perhaps the cartridge is defective or after-market ones are not worth using?  I took the cartridge out and rotated around the long axis several times back and forth, but the printing was no different.

Second, I recently moved, could some damaged have occurred during moving (I replaced the cartridge right before moving and do not recall if this issue existed before moving.)

If it is the first, I just buy an official HP cartridge, if not, I get a new printer.

Comment: Are you trying to print a page with a non-white background?

Comment: No, this is happening for black text on white background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is almost 7 years too late, but I believe it may be the definitive answer to the washed-out prints on the LaserJet 1200/1300 printers.

I recently spent several months trying to find the cause of this problem on my LaserJet 1300 (nearly identical to your LaserJet 1200). I too, had been using an off-brand toner cartridge (Cartridge World), and at some point it stopped being recognized by the printer. After replacing the cartridge, I had prints, but they were faded so much that the pages could almost be mistaken for blank.

I tried *everything* mentioned in the other comments and answers, and spent hours combing the internet for information on this problem. I cleaned every accessible part, including the corona wires, and replaced the toner cartridge with a brand new HP cartridge. I even took the laser off and cleaned the mirror (unnecessary). Some references online mention that the photo-sensitive roller in the cartridge can go bad on the shelf (it didn't, I tried a second brand new HP toner cartridge with the same result).

Finally, I disassembled the entire printer piece by piece because I was determined to save it (after 16 years without a single problem, I had some loyalty to this thing).

In my case, the problem was a faulty zEngine Controller Board - it destroyed a toner cartridge in the process (or perhaps the cartridge itself developed a fault that shorted out the board). I replaced the controller board with a used one from eBay for about $19. As soon I removed the original board, I could see a row of resistors with burn marks (R540-R544 next to the large capacitor).

The zEngine Controller Board is accessible from the back of the printer:

[image: LaserJet 1300 zEngine Controller Board]

The area of the fault on the board:

[image: faulty LaserJet 1300 zEngine Controller Board]

A closer look at the blown resistors:

[image: blown resistors on LaserJet 1300 zEngine Controller Board]

And here are the test pages after replacing the board:

[image: test pages after replacing zEngine Controller Board]

Replacing the board was pretty easy, but I wouldn't call it trivial. It took about three hours even with YouTube videos showing the entire process ([this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40-Cl2gh5VM) about removing the fuser will get you most of the way there). The good news is that it only took patience and a couple of decent Phillips screwdrivers (two sizes).

In retrospect, the source of the fault may well have been the toner cartridge, because both that and the board needed to be replaced in order get a functioning printer again. Additionally, the off-brand toner replacement leaked toner into some hard-to-clean areas in the printer. From now on, I'm spending the extra money on the HP cartridges.

Comment: Hmm... the controller board looks more like a power supply to me, based on the "primary"/"secondary" silkscreens on the PCB and the large power transistor next to the resistors you mentioned. I'm more curious if the problem was in fact caused by that transistor overheating? Power supplies can and do fail in destructive ways, especially given the high temperatures inside a laser printer...

Comment: Also, that board generates high voltages. The high-voltage power supply board is a common point of failure for laser printers. **Use extreme caution when handling that board; it is an electrocution hazard.**

Comment: @bwDraco Yes, this board is also the power supply, although it has only a single large capacitor. I had thoughts of testing the components in that area of the board, but once I had a working printer I decided to quit while I was ahead. None of the capacitors showed signs of leakage or bulging, and the only signs of damage were the scorch marks around those resistors.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with an HP Laserjet 8150 DN.  I was thinking it was a drum issue, but after reading this I have another culprit to potentially look at.

Answer (score 7):

To understand this better, you may want to read about [how laser printing works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printing#Mechanism).

A gray cast indicates that the drum is not getting or holding a sufficiently strong charge to hold the toner.  It looks like either the OPC drum or the corona wire/primary charge roller is not working correctly.  Try replacing the cartridge (the drum is part of the cartridge in many HP laser printers, including yours).  If this does not work, the printer needs to be serviced.

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing the toner, try cleaning the drum with some cleaning paper (toilet paper might do the trick), this is the (usualy) green roller hiding behind the protection you will need to lift. If I recall correctly,  this protection is on the right side on this picture. Try printing to see if it got any better. Good luck!

[image: Image of the 15A toner cartridge]

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

I read it is the wiper blade getting too old and stiff. Need to change the cartridge. I have that happen to me a few times, usually with re-manufactured toner cartridge.